# joi.label , what does this method of joi schema validation do

Tags: joi

I just came across this line of code that I had to work on:

`Joi.array().label('Emails').items(Joi.string()).required()`

I particularly didn't understand what `.label('Emails')` was doing, so, I hit the documentation:

> Overrides the key name in error messages.
>
> ```
> name - the name of the key.
> ```
>
> const schema = {
> first_name: Joi.string().label('First Name') };

and this particularly didn't make any sense to me. Because, is `First Name`, `Emails` particular parameters that can be passed? What is it overriding? What other arguments can we pass, etc. What is this method doing particularly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have this schema:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  first_name: Joi.string().label('First Name')
});
```

and you validate an invalid object (passing `first_name` as `number` type):

```
const { error, value } = schema.validate({ first_name: 123 })
```

This is how the `error.details` object will look like:

```
[
  {
    message: 'first_name must be a string',
    path: [ 'first_name' ],
    type: 'string.base',
    context: {
      label: 'First Name',
      valids: 123,
      key: 'first_name'
    }
  }
]
```

However, if you use `.label('First Name')` this is what you get from the error object:

```
[
  {
    message: 'First Name must be a string', <-- OVERRIDES
    path: [ 'first_name' ],
    type: 'string.base',
    context: {
      label: 'First Name', <-- OVERRIDES
      valids: 123,
      key: 'first_name'
    }
  }
]
```

So, `.label` will override the `message` and the `context.label`.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anylabelname) you can't pass any other argument.